# EInvalidOperation exception when trying to create a parented VCL TFrame in a type library

Tags: delphi, com, activex, pascal, vcl

I have two projects, A and B. A is a Windows VCL application and B is an ActiveX server application. B exposes a type library hosted using COM. This type library is called by A. I am trying to pass B a handle of A's main window and have B create a VCL `TFrame` using that handle as a parent control. Finally, I am trying to return this VCL `TFrame` back to A in the form of a pointer.

I am getting the following exception:

> Project A raised exception class EInvalidOperation with message
>   'Control 'MainFrame' has no parent window. Path: MainFrame'.

I have narrowed down the line of code, shown below as `MainFrame := TMainFrame.CreateParented(ParentHandle);`, that causes trouble in the following COM object function of Project B:

```
function DelphiCOMServiceImplementation.GetDelphiVCLFramePointer(pointer: Pointer; width: Double; height: Double): Pointer; stdcall;
begin
  ParentHandle := Cardinal(pointer);
  MainFrame := TMainFrame.CreateParented(ParentHandle); // This is the line that causes the exception.
  MainFrame.Width := Trunc(width);
  MainFrame.Height := Trunc(height);
  MainHandle := MainFrame.Handle;
  MainPointer := System.Pointer(MainHandle);
  Result := MainPointer;
end;
```

Above, `TMainFrame` is just a simple VCL `TFrame` that hosts a `TLabel`.

**Why does this error occur, and what can I do to fix it? Essentially, I would like to be able to construct my `TFrame` control successfully, with or without a parent control, and then I would like to return that `TFrame`'s handle back from my COM object to the caller.**

I have checked the pointers and the cardinal I pass in retains its value in the COM object. The reason why I am trying to perform this task is that I ultimately want to call my COM object from another technology, but for now I am just having these issues solely within the world of Delphi and I must remedy them.

Here is how I have set up my COM object in B:

```
unit DelphiCOMServiceUnit;

interface

uses SysUtils, ComObj, ComServ, DelphiCOMService_TLB, Winapi.ActiveX, StdVcl, Frame, Vcl.Forms, Winapi.Windows;

type
  DelphiCOMServiceImplementation = class(TComObject, IDelphiCOMService)
  private
    MainFrame: TMainFrame;
    MainHandle: Cardinal;
    ParentHandle: Cardinal;
    MainPointer: Pointer;
  protected
    function GetDelphiVCLFramePointer(pointer: Pointer; width: Double; height: Double): Pointer; stdcall;
    procedure WindowResized(width: Double; height: Double); safecall;
  end;

implementation

function DelphiCOMServiceImplementation.GetDelphiVCLFramePointer(pointer: Pointer; width: Double; height: Double): Pointer; stdcall;
begin
  ParentHandle := Cardinal(pointer);
  MainFrame := TMainFrame.CreateParented(ParentHandle);
  MainFrame.Width := Trunc(width);
  MainFrame.Height := Trunc(height);
  MainHandle := MainFrame.Handle;
  MainPointer := System.Pointer(MainHandle);
  Result := MainPointer;
end;

procedure DelphiCOMServiceImplementation.WindowResized(width: Double; height: Double); safecall;
begin
  MainFrame.Width := Trunc(width);
  MainFrame.Height := Trunc(height);
end;

initialization

TComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, DelphiCOMServiceImplementation, StringToGUID('{D448873F-EAF7-4F40-8BC7-EF9853E64A0F}'), 'DelphiCOMServiceImplementation', '', ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);

end.
```

Here is how I invoke this COM object from A:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Service := CoDelphiCOMServiceImplementation.Create();
  Parent := Pointer(Handle);
  Service.GetDelphiVCLFramePointer(Parent, 1337, 1337);
end;
```

A is just a simple VCL Windows application which has one form on it. I've binded a `FormActivate` event wherein I call B with the handle of the current form.

Also, for completion, here is how I set up my *.ridl:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do some debugging to find out what value is passed to GetDelphiVCLFramePointer. Also, what value does Application.Handle have. In fact you should be able to debug this and break on the VCL code that raises the exception. If I faced this problem, that's where I would start.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I debugged through a run from A to B. From the caller's side: `Handle` = 658454. `Parent` = $A0C16. `Application.Handle` = 1116886. `Application.MainFormHandle` = 658454. From the type library's side: `pointer` = $A0C16. `ParentHandle` = 658454. So basically, the `Cardinal` I pass in is the same on both sides.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is so bizarre. Debugged some more inside of `Vcl.Controls`. When its working (without COM, pure Delphi), `Vlc.Controls` evaluates this line to false: `if (WndParent = 0) and (Style and WS_CHILD <> 0)`. Over COM, that line is true. Also over COM, `WndParent` gets set to the following non-zero window: `WndParent := FParentWindow;` so how can it possibly evaluate to true for that statement? It would mean something else is setting `WndParent` to 0 or something more nefarious like, maybe the `HWnd`'s memory is getting corrupted or being cleaned up by COM?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan On the positive flip-side of things, I have no issues creating a new `TForm` within my COM object and showing it, so maybe I'll just embed my `TFrame` inside of that window and see if that works...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was able to achieve what I wanted in a different way, although it doesn’t answer the question. I was able to add the frame to a form, show the form, and then return the handle to the frame. Furthermore, I was able to reparent the handle to the frame to a WPF window of mine and essentially host a VCL frame in a WPF window, which was my ultimate end goal here for this exercise. Now, I have to figure out how to visualize the form without showing the window, or alternatively showing the window invisible but with the frame section visible.

Comment: Corruption of memory isn't likely. Don't make the mistake of imagining gremlins. Use your debugger to find out what the value of WndParent is, and what the value of Style is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Two things. One: Force of habit I’ve developed over the years is to imagine all the problems, including those that don’t actually exist. Two: Delphi won’t actually let me debug the values of those two properties. I tried even adding them to a watch, but its not liking me fiddling in there despite being on a debug build with no optimizations. I can only seem to infer what they should be set to based on other properties or variables they get set to in other functions. Not sure if I am missing some debug properties that would otherwise show their values.

Comment: They are members of the Params record. They aren't properties. That code is evaluated inside a with I believe. Write Params.WndParent in the debugger evaluator.